# Objective C: Bending images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

I want to take an image and have the user bend it and take it apart. I've been searching for a while and can't find anything similar to the idea. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What does "bending" an image look like? Can you show an example?

Comment: Like, lets say you have a paperclip. You touch one end and bring it down with your finger, it'll smoothly bend it into 90 degrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bending(like Curl effect),use

[UIImageView transitionFromView:image1 toView:image2 duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:NULL];

in any gesture.